# Combining S-parametric Blocks

Tags: circuit-analysis, matrix, s-parameters

I would like to ask you, please, how I can combine general S-parametric blocks together. Consider the situation in the following picture.

[image: System example.]

Considering this example, I would like to connect these three blocks together to obtain one 2-port block. In circuit simulators, this means connecting corresponding pins together. But I would like to know, how can I do it directly with s-parameters matrices.

And from these three matrices, I would like to receive one 2-port scattering matrix. This is just an example, but I would like to know a general procedure for this.

I have tried to search for this but all I have got is only how to put together a series of 2-port networks.

I will be glad for any help.

Comment: I am sorry for the broken equations. It looks alright in the editor. I do not know how to repair it.

Comment: Your choices are either do a crapload of algebra, or plug it into a simulator like ADS and let a computer do a crapload of algebra for you. Or if you're a whiz at Maple or Mathematica you could maybe get a computer to do the algebra that way.

Comment: Are you trying to do this by hand? Do you have the matrix elements as numbers or as formulae dependent on frequency? Or do you want to write a computer program to solve the general case based on some kind of input from the user? Please be more specific about the problem you're trying to solve. (You can probably just erase the mixed up equations --- I think the general problem is clear without them)

Comment: I would like to write a program that will do that connection for me. I certainly do not want to do this by hand. But I would need some hint on how to do that crapload of algebra.